# Is this a valid monad transformer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

In order to better understand monad transformers I implemented one. Since Javascript is dynamically typed I don't mimic type or data constructors but declare only plain old Javascript objects, which hold the corresponding static functions to form a specific monad / transformer. The underlying idea is to apply these methods to a value/values in a container type. Types and containers are separated so to speak.

`Array`s can contain any number of elements. It is trivial to extend `Array`s so that they implement the monad interface. `Array`s can also represent the two variants of the `maybe` type. An empty `Array` corresponds to `nothing`. An `Array` with a single element corresponds to `just(a)`. Consequently I will use `Array`s as my container type. Please note that this is an quick and dirty implementation just for learning:

```
const array = {
  of: x => Array.of(x),
  map: f => ftor => ftor.map(f),
  ap: ftor => gtor => array.flatten(array.map(f => array.map(f) (gtor)) (ftor)),
  flatten: ftor => ftor.reduce((xs, y) => xs.concat(y), []),
  chain: mf => ftor => array.flatten(array.map(mf) (ftor))
}

const maybe = {
  of: array.of,
  empty: () => [],
  throw: ftor => { if (ftor.length > 1) throw Error("indeterministic value"); return ftor },
  map: f => ftor => maybe.throw(ftor).map(f),
  ap: ftor => gtor => maybe.flatten(maybe.map(f => maybe.map(f) (gtor)) (ftor)),
  flatten: array.flatten,
  chain: mf => ftor => maybe.flatten(maybe.map(mf) (ftor)),
  T: M => {
    return {
      of: x => M.of(maybe.of(x)),
      empty: () => M.of(maybe.empty()),
      map: f => ftor => M.map(gtor => maybe.map(f) (gtor)) (ftor),
      ap: ftor => gtor => M.flatten(M.map(htor => M.map(itor => maybe.ap(htor) (itor)) (gtor)) (ftor)),
      flatten: maybe.flatten,
      chain: mf => ftor => M.chain(gtor => maybe.chain(mf) (gtor)) (ftor)
    };
  }
};
```

Now I combine a maybe transformer with the monadic array to get a monad that can handle `array`s of `maybe`s.

```
const arraym = maybe.T(array);

const add = x => y => x + y;
const addm = x => y => [x + y];
const arrayOfMaybes = [[1],[],[3]]
```

When I treat `arraym` as an applicative functor, everything works as expected:

```
// yields: [[11],[],[13]] as expected
arraym.ap(arraym.map(add) (arrayOfMaybes)) (arraym.of(10));
```

However, when I apply `chain` something goes wrong:

```
// yields: [11,13] but [[11],[13]] expected
arraym.chain(x => arraym.chain(y => addm(x) (y)) (arrayOfMaybes)) ([[10]])
```

Is the cause of this problem

- that this isn't a valid monad transformer?
- that the way I apply chain is wrong?
- that my expectation regarding the result is wrong?

Comment: `arraym.flatten` looks wrong

Comment: I guess using a proper `Maybe` with a non-array representation would have exposed the type error you made by throwing instead of returning a mis-nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the cause of this problem that the way I apply chain is wrong?

Yes. You need to pass an `mf` that returns an `arraym`, not an `array` like `addm` does. You could use

```
const addmm = x => y => array.map(maybe.of)(addm(x)(y))
arraym.chain(x => arraym.chain( addmm(x) )(arrayOfMaybes))([[10]])
```

To help with this, you also might consider implementing [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift) for every monad transformer.

Comment: That's a good hint. I will take a closer look at this. I guess every transformer needs a specific lift function. Thanks!

Comment: The incorrectly lifted `addm` function was in fact the cause. It seems that both the outer and inner monad computation was applied correctly, but the resulting monad lost the maybe type, hence I got an `Array` of `Number`s. I wonder if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: @ftor it's a bug stemming from using only arrays instead of separate list and maybe types. Of course you could call it a feature :-)

Comment: ...it feels like a catamorphism. But you're probably right. At least my little hack is honest with the fact that Javascript doesn't have types.